# Trying to use pubnub with lumen

Tags: lumen, pubnub

Im trying to use pubnub with lumen, and failing spectacularly.

Its in the vendor folder under pubnub/pubnub/composer/lib/autoloader.php
Or pubnub/pubnub/composer/lib/Pubnub/Pubnub.php.

How exactly do I access this??

Ive tried puttint it in bootstrap/app.php like so...

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/pubnub/pubnub/composer/lib/Pubnub/Pubnub.php';
```

and...

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/pubnub/pubnub/composer/lib/autoloader.php';
```

That didnt work.  I've tried doing that in the actual controller file that I need it in.  That didnt work either because of namespacing.  I feel like I'm being really stupid right now, but how the hell do I just access this class!?

PS: I don't want to use Broadcasting built into Lumen.  As this is just a one off route, that doesnt need all that complexity.  I simply just want to fire off a Pubnub simply by loading the class, and doing it.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Lumen but sounds like a PHP way to do Amazon Functions? yes/no? What is failing? Are there any error messages? Is your PubNub code running? When you say *fire off a PubNub* do you mean execute a `publish` call?